How to display confusion matrix in R using highcharter?
actually i am new to R and i was wondering how to use the highcharter package to create a confusion matrix . Would be glad if someone can help !
I looked around a bit and saw maybe we could use a heatmap but is there any other way ?

Hi Riddhi Kulkarni, welcome to SO. I recommend you provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking this type of question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks
